# How to efficiently copy all files from one directory to another in an amazon S3 bucket with boto?

Tags: python, performance, amazon-s3, copy-paste, boto

I need to copy all keys from '/old/dir/' to '/new/dir/' in an amazon S3 bucket. 
I came up with this script (quick hack):

```
import boto

s3 = boto.connect_s3()
thebucket = s3.get_bucket("bucketname")
keys = thebucket.list('/old/dir')
for k in keys:
    newkeyname = '/new/dir' + k.name.partition('/old/dir')[2]
    print 'new key name:', newkeyname
    thebucket.copy_key(newkeyname, k.bucket.name, k.name)
```

For now it is working but is much slower than what I can do manually in the graphical managment console by just copy/past with the mouse. Very frustrating and there are lots of keys to copy...

Do you know any quicker method ? Thanks.

Edit: maybe I can do this with concurrent copy processes. I'm not really familiar with boto copy keys methods and how many concurrent processes I can send to amazon.

Edit2: i'm currently learning Python multiprocessing. Let's see if I can send 50 copy operations simultaneously...

Edit 3: I tried with 30 concurrent copy using Python multiprocessing module. Copy was much faster than within the console and less error prone. There is a new issue with large files (>5Gb): boto raises an exception. I need to debug this before posting the updated script.

Comment: Have you tried REST-copying an object (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html?r=7426)? I would give it a try, maybe it is quicker...

Comment: I hope boto is calling this API already, but I did not check

Comment: So do I :) But I learned the hard way it does not hurt checking...

Comment: I'm getting horrible performance as well on this stuff. Opened https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/793

Comment: Yes, boto is calling REST copy API. In [boto/provider.py](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/provider.py#L106) you can see it using header 'x-amz-copy-source' as described in the link Viccari gave in his previous comment.

Comment: Can you post your multiprocessing code

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your issue with files over 5GB: S3 doesn't support uploading files over 5GB using the PUT method, which is what boto tries to do ([see boto source](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/8a17715eae1f8e54fb08eb2fa7be4e8ac505d349/boto/s3/bucket.py#L682), [Amazon S3 documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#How_much_data_can_I_store)).

Unfortunately I'm not sure how you can get around this, apart from downloading it and re-uploading in a multi-part upload. I don't think boto supports a multi-part copy operation yet (if such a thing even exists)